# How to enable registry and command prompt when they are both disabled along with gpedit.msc and run command

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-registry, gpedit

I was testing group policy and disabled all registry editing tools along with command prompt and group policy editor itself, pretty much everything is disabled!
How can i enable what i have disabled ?

Answer (score 1):

Run the following 2 commands from the Run prompt:

```
REG add "HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System" /v DisableCMD /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

REG add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /t Reg_dword /v DisableRegistryTools /f /d 0
```

Comment: run command is disabled too!

Comment: In that case, I'd boot into recovery console and run those commands. Additionally, you might try some of the programs in this article. It's for when a virus disables those tools, but the end result should be the same for you. :)
https://www.raymond.cc/blog/restore-task-manager-regedit-and-folder-options-disabled-by-virus/

Comment: no luck! they actually are using registry modification to revert back the changes, I disabled registry modification as well!:(
there are some ways to enable registry editing through cmd, then cmd is disabled as well, the last resort was using group policy, which again is disabled !!! and i think i am dead!!